# All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided

Tags: stellar-sdk

**Describe the problem**
This problem appears when I want to participate in development , I clone the project javascript **stellar-sdk**  then run 
`npm install`

**What version are you on?**
4.1.0

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:
1. clone the project from git
2. run `npm install`

**Expected behavior**

```
you should see the following error
> gulp build

[14:00:41] Using gulpfile D:\projects\stellar-sdk\gulpfile.js
[14:00:41] Starting 'build'...
[14:00:41] Starting 'clean'...
[14:00:41] Finished 'clean' after 52 ms
[14:00:41] Starting 'build:node'...
[14:00:41] Starting 'buildNode'...
src/browser.ts:3:1 - error TS1208: All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.

3 module.exports = require("./index");
  ~~~~~~


Found 1 error.

[14:00:44] 'buildNode' errored after 2.46 s
[14:00:44] Error: Command failed: npx tsc
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:657:15)
    at buildNode (D:\projects\kuknos-sdk\gulpfile.js:43:12)
    at bound (domain.js:420:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:433:12)
    at asyncRunner (D:\projects\kuknos-sdk\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

**Additional context**
I have edited the file **browser.ts** as follow

```
`export * from "./index";`
```

but then it will face with the following error

```
The following tasks did not complete: build, build:browser, buildBrowser
[13:57:13] Did you forget to signal async completion?
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! stellar-sdk@4.1.0 prepare: `gulp build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
```

this is the case when I set `isolatedModules` false in **tsconfig.json**